# OData $expand produces odd error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

When I try to use an OData query with $expand the following error is produced:

```
DbIsOfExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and Google doesn't really reveal much behind that error. All of the references for the project are fine, and all other OData queries work as expected.

Here's are the relevant data models:

```
public class ViewLink
{
    public string OverrideLinkName { get; set; }

    public string OverrideDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int ViewLinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> ViewID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> CreatedByID { get; set; }

    public virtual View View { get; set; }

    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
}

public partial class View
{
    public Nullable<int> SchoolID { get; set; }

    public string ViewName { get; set; }

    public int ViewID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> ViewTypeID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> TeacherID { get; set; }

    public virtual ViewType ViewType { get; set; }
```

}

```
public partial class ViewType
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> Priority { get; set; }

    public int ViewTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

The error is produced when I try to use the following OData query:

`http://apilinkhere.com/api/viewlink?$top=1&$expand=View/ViewType`

Is there a setting I need to change somewhere? I just want to be led in the right direction behind what I'm doing wrong, and come to an understanding of what is happening here. I don't want to continue to have this error in future projects.

If there is something else that is needed I'll do my best to produce it.

EDIT:

I'm using Web API OData.

Comment: Does it concern `ASP.NET Web API OData`? There is also `WCF Data Service` which is different, it would be good to specify that in your question.

Comment: This suggests that at least one type has subtypes that you should query explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between View and ViewType? In your code, it seems that ViewType is a navigation property of View. If so, the query should be ....?$expand=View($expand=ViewType).

Comment: ViewType is a navigation property. I attempted your query but received the following error: "Term 'View($expand=ViewType)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression."

Comment: Sorry, I miss the "?" in the answer. I have edited it. And if further problems, you can refer to http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/SelectExpandDollarValueSample/ This gives a detailed implementation and request URL of $select and $expand.